# C Homework, Print out the binary value of an integer

Tags: c, binary

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

// Print out the binary value of an integer

void binval (int num);
int get_number();

main () {
  int num;

  num = get_number();
  printf("Num = %d\n",num);
  binval(num);

}

void binval (int num) {
  int val = 0;
  int test;

  if (!num) {
    printf("\n");
    return;
  }


  test = num & 0x0001;
  if (test == 1) {
    val = 1;
 }

  num = num / 2;
  printf("%d",val);
  binval(num);
  return;
}

int get_number() { 
  int value = 0;
  char c;
  printf("Please input number : ");
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') { 
    if ( (c>'9') || (c<'0') ) { 
      printf("Incorrect character entered as a number - %c\n",c);
      exit(-1);
    }
    else {
      value = 10*value + c - '0';
    }
  }
  return(value);
}
```

now it compiles just get 01 for every answer.

Comment: For reference, if you add or change code in the question, you should probably add the new version after (or at least comment what's changed) in order to help others that have the same problem.  As it is, it's not obvious why we keep telling you to do stuff you've already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `binval` in `main` implicitly declares it like `int binval(int)`.

In order to fix that, you'll need to either add a forward declaration for `binval`, or move `main` to after `binval`.

After that, and after fixing the other stuff mentioned in other answers, we still have one little problem: the bits will be printed out backwards, because you're printing the least significant bit first.  The easiest way to fix that is to switch the `binval` and `printf` within the `binval` function itself, but of course you probably won't want the base case (num==0) to print a newline.  Just print a newline after you call the function from `main`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to declare your `binval` function, or the compiler assumes it returns `int`.  Then when you define it, it doesn't match that assumption.

Also, this line will likely give you trouble:

```
if (test = 1) {
```

This will assign `test` to the value 1, but I think you meant to compare it:

```
if (test == 1) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the prototype of binval above main like 
void binval(int);

or 
copy the whole binval function above main.

Raghu

Comment: ok, fixing that made it compile, but now I get the wrong binary output, thank you for your help, I will now try to figure out what else is wrong.

Comment: @pisfire - Some useful hints are given in the answers below. You can make a note of it.

Comment: I got it thanks to everyones help.  How come it would not work with the declaration void binval(int num); but would work with void binval(int);

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems I can see:

- Declare the function `binval` before
  main as `void binval (int num);`
- Function get_number() returns the
  number read but you are not
  collecting it in num. So
  `get_number();` should be 
  `num =     get_number();`
- `if (test = 1)` should be `if (test
  == 1)`
- Your current logic print the binary
  value of the number in **reverse**.
  You need to fix that.

Comment: ok I knew I had a problem with num, I will see if that fixes it

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function before the `main()` just like you did `int get_number();`
 or you can define all your functions before `main()`.

This is called [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

Comment: This was just a dumb mistake on my part, just getting tired.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
void binval (int num) {
  /* ... */
  printf("%d",val);
  binval(num);
  return;
}
```

which, for 16, prints "00001". Try recursing **first** and print after.

```
void binval (int num) {
  /* ... */
  binval(num);
  printf("%d",val);
  return;
}
```

Comment: I had given up on being able to fix this part.  Thank you.

Comment: Out of my entire junior class only one other person got this.  I am very impressed you caught that.

Comment: I run your code. It was easy to detect the error ... and once I knew that that particular error existed, easy to fix :)